# immediate 429 when submitting mp4's using API through Make (formerly known as Integromat)

Tags: api, imgur, make.com, integromat-apps

I use Make/Integromat to automatically upload .mp4 files. Sometimes this works fine, other times I get 429 errors immediately when uploading. Even from the first file. [image]

I contacted Make support, they analyzed the error logs, but only got the 429 back, nothing more.

Normally speaking, I only upload ~20 files per day. So well within the API limits. And when they're successful and I check the API limits, I'm well within range.

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit per IP address in Imgur.

Your use of the Imgur API is also limited by the number of POST requests your IP can make across all endpoints. This limit is 1,250 POST requests per hour.

See the document [here](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#:%7E:text=Your%20use%20of%20the%20Imgur,1%2C250%20POST%20requests%20per%20hour.).

Since, Make performs HTTP request from handful of IP address, it might be the reason you are getting this error, which is really bad.